# Hyperlink after Vlookup

Tags: vba, excel, hyperlink

This simple thing is eating my brain out. Here is the challenge:

I have 2 sheets in the same workbook. Say Sheet 1 and Sheet 2. I want to Vlookup for the value present in Sheet 1 Column A and Sheet 2 column B. If the value is found i want to put a hyperlink in Sheet 1 Column A to point it to Sheet 2 Column D. In simple words, there are program names present in both the sheets and associated risk in sheet 2. If the program is present in both the sheets then i want to navigate directly to the risk present in the Sheet 2 upon clicking the program name in Sheet1.

I am attaching the sample file with this thread. Please somebody help me. I have tried with vba and normal formulas. Nothing is being worked out.

SAmple file can be downloaded from [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-Mgxdw-FueaVnBmLXBWZmZGVjA&authuser=0)

Comment: Your sample file link leads to a pasword protected log-in. So how do we see it?

Comment: @MarkFitzgerald I'm Sorry. I have edited the post. You can try now. [Sample file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-Mgxdw-FueaVnBmLXBWZmZGVjA&authuser=0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you can do that with a formula. You'll need to change the workbook name in the HYPERLINK formula to match yours.

```
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP($A1,Sheet2!$B:$B,1,0)),"",HYPERLINK("[StackTest.xlsx]'Sheet2'!D"&TEXT(MATCH($A1,Sheet2!$B:$B,0),"#"),"Click Here"))
```